# Typeset all caps to bold and all small to italics in math environment

Tags: math-mode, bold, italic, amsfonts

I want to typeset all capital letters/symbols to be bold and all small letter to be italics in math environment **by default**. I was wondering how can I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    Var[aX+bY] = a^2Var[X] + 2ab Cov[X,Y] + b^2 Var[Y]
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, only `X` and `Y` should b bold, whereas `Var` and `Cov` upright as words/operators (short for "variance" and "covariance"). Defining and using `\X` and `\Y` for `\mathbf{X}` and `\mathbf{Y}` is a good compromise IMHO.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}
\newcommand*{\X}{\mathbf{X}}
\newcommand*{\Y}{\mathbf{Y}}

\begin{document}
\[
    \Var[a\X+b\Y] = a^2\Var[\X] + 2ab \Cov[\X,\Y] + b^2 \Var[\Y]
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`X` and `Y` also could be make bold by default, when in math. Then the original uppercase letters for bold are available as `\orgX` and `\orgY`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}

\newcommand*{\MakeMathBold}[1]{%
  \expandafter\MakeMathBoldAux\csname org#1\endcsname{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\MakeMathBoldAux}[2]{%
  \mathchardef#1=\the\mathcode`#2\relax
  \begingroup
    \lccode`~=`#2\relax
  \lowercase{\endgroup
    \def~{\mathbf{#1}}%
  }%
  \mathcode`#2="8000\relax
}

\MakeMathBold{X}
\MakeMathBold{Y}

\begin{document}
\[
    \Var[aX+bY] = a^2\Var[X] + 2ab \Cov[X,Y] + b^2 \Var[Y]
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case `\mathit{A}` or `\mathnormal{A}` would not work.

Comment: @egreg Both `\mathit{A}` and `\mathnormal{A}` work in both cases, since `A` is never touched. In the first example, `\mathsf{XY}` works as expected, in the second example, `\mathsf{\orgX\orgY}` should be used.

Comment: The A was just for example. Anyway, you're missing `\MakeMathBold{X}` and `\MakeMathBold{Y}`.

Comment: @egreg Nice to have three complete different solutions in two answers: Pure macros, active characters in math mode, and the math font based solution from you. All three of them have different advantages and disadvantages. All of them can create normal uppercase letters: `X`, `\orgX`, `\mathnormal{X}`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to redeclare the math code for the uppercase letters after defining a new symbol font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{boldletters}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{bx}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbf}{boldletters}

\DeclareMathSymbol{A}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{B}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{C}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{D}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{E}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{F}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{G}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`G}
\DeclareMathSymbol{H}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`H}
\DeclareMathSymbol{I}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`I}
\DeclareMathSymbol{J}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`J}
\DeclareMathSymbol{K}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`K}
\DeclareMathSymbol{L}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`L}
\DeclareMathSymbol{M}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`M}
\DeclareMathSymbol{N}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`N}
\DeclareMathSymbol{O}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`O}
\DeclareMathSymbol{P}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`P}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Q}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`Q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{R}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`R}
\DeclareMathSymbol{S}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`S}
\DeclareMathSymbol{T}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`T}
\DeclareMathSymbol{U}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`U}
\DeclareMathSymbol{V}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`V}
\DeclareMathSymbol{W}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`W}
\DeclareMathSymbol{X}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`X}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Y}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`Y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Z}{\mathalpha}{boldletters}{`Z}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}

\begin{document}

\[
\Var[aX+bY] = a^2\Var[X] + 2ab \Cov[X,Y] + b^2 \Var[Y]
\]

\end{document}
```

The occasional italic uppercase letter can be obtained with `\mathnormal{A}`

[image]